# Ejecutar onClick del padre y de mi componente custom

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Cree un checkbox custom, le setee un onCliclListener propio a la view, para que se me modifique la vista (cambie el check) y ademas realize otra accion mas.
Pero ademas de eso, tambien necesito que realize el onClickListener que le asigno desde el padre, como puedo hacer posible esto?

```
public cc_CheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
    View v = inflate(context, R.layout.cc_check_box, this);
    v.setOnClickListener(this::cambiarEstado);
}
```

cambiarEstado es mi funcion, y desde el padre:

```
cc_CheckBox cccb = v.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
cccb.setOnClickListener(this::funcion);
```

El resultado de esto, es que solo ejecuta la funcion del padre, y no estoy encontrando la forma de que ejecute ambas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo la solucion

Lo que hice fue crear un atributo onClickListener

```
private View.OnClickListener OCN;
```

Un setter para ese atributo

```
public void setOnClick(View.OnClickListener ocl) {
        OCN = ocl;
    }
```

Y desde el onClcik del componente ejecuto su propio onClick y el del atributo

```
private boolean cambiarEstado(View v) {
    estado = !estado;
    cambiarImagen();
    OCN.onClick(v);
    return false;
}
```